# Rest Service Getting invoked on local but not on aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jersey-2.0

I created a web-app with Jersey 2.0 REST APIs. It is working perfectly fine on my local machine but when I deployed my application on AWS the RESTFul Services are not getting called.

Below is the scenario:

The below service URL works perfectly fine on my local machine. Context path of my app is /testrest.

http://localhost:8080/testrest/test/rest

[image]

When deployed On AWS(Tomcat 8 Java 8) the below doesn't work and give me 404 error:

http://testrest.wm5zqpd6m2.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/testrest/rest/test

But the interesting thing is if i remove the word testrest and hit the below url it returns a success response. Plz try clicking on the links and see the results. I am attaching my pom.xml, web.xml and my resource class.

http://testrest.wm5zqpd6m2.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/rest/test

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>testrest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>testrest Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>testrest</finalName>

    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.testing
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Resource Class:

```
package com.testing;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
public class TestRest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/test")
    public Response testRest(){

        return Response.ok("Success Again and Again", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't _testrest.wm5zqpd6m2.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com_ is base context on AWS for your application?

Comment: @Sanjeev I am not sure. I am very new to aws and using it for first time. Don't know of there is any configuration like that

Comment: by default that is how AWS treats root contexts. Please see [this forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=229121&#229121)

Comment: @HiteshBhutani Did you solve this issue? I am also hitting similar issue. I would appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: @Azim Do you use aws window instance or linux instance?

Comment: @Azim I believe you seems to be using Linux instance. Problem is that the war get deployed as a root and not with your application context. Just google it and see how to deploy war with application context on aws linux. I eventually moved away from Linux and uses AWS Windows as I am not well versed in linux OS. But your problem has definitely to do with context of the application. I would suggest just trying with a very small Rest Service like the one i have above.

Comment: @Azim Also you can refer to this link if your problem is more like this. There is an internal link as well in this post. http://serverfault.com/questions/629105/cant-access-site-on-ec2-instance-via-public-ip

Comment: @HiteshBhutani: I will go through this link. Thanks, for replying :)